# fastest way to send mails using phpmailer smtp?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i am using following phpmailer function to send 1000+ mails

```
<?php
function sendMail($sendTo,$Subject,$Body){

    require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com;smtp.example.com';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
    $mail->Username = 'newsletter@example.com';           
    $mail->Password = 'password';                         
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    
    $mail->From = 'newsletter@example.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'xyz';
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  

    $mail->addAddress($sendTo);               
    $mail->Subject = $Subject;
    $mail->Body = ( stripslashes( $Body ) );
    $mail->AltBody = 'Please Use a Html email Client To view This Message!!';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $return = 'Message could not be sent.';
        // echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        $return = 'Message has been sent!';
    }
    return $return;
}
```

and this is the code i am using to call function

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
 $subject = "sample subject";
 $body = "sample body";
 sendMail($email, $subject, $body);
}
```

size of $emails array is 1000+
is there any faster and better way to do this?

Comment: There is - use MTA (eg. postfix)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should start by [reading the docs provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists) where you will find [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Of particular note in there, make sure you use `SMTPKeepAlive` - you may find benefit in sorting your list by domain to maximise connection re-use.

As zerkms said, you should submit to a local mail server for best performance, though surprisingly using `mail` or `sendmail` options in PHPMailer is not always faster than SMTP to localhost, largely because postfix' sendmail binary opens a synchronous SMTP connection to localhost anyway - postfix' docs recommend SMTP to localhost for best performance for this reason.

If you are sending to localhost, don't use auth or encryption as the overhead doesn't gain you anything, but if you are using a remote server, use tls on port 587 in preference to the obsolete ssl on port 465.

Generally sending directly to end users is to be avoided - the SMTP client in PHPMailer is somewhat dumb - it does not handle queuing at all, so any domains with greylisting or delivery deferrals for traffic control will fail to be delivered. the best approach is to use SMTP to a nearby MTA and leave the queue handling to that. You can get bounces back from that as well so you can remove bad addresses from your list.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this should work.

Basically, it reuses the original object (thus reducing memory allocations).

```
require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

class BatchMailer {

    var $mail;

    function __construct () {
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer;
        $this->mail->isSMTP();
        $this->mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com;smtp.example.com';
        $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->mail->Username = 'newsletter@example.com';
        $this->mail->Password = 'password';
        $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $this->mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
        $this->mail->Port = 465;
        $this->mail->From = 'newsletter@example.com';
        $this->mail->FromName = 'xyz';
        $this->mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $this->mail->isHTML(true);
        $this->mail->AltBody = 'Please use an HTML-enabled email client to view this message.';
    }

    function setSubject ($subject) {
        $this->mail->Subject = $subject;
    }

    function setBody ($body) {
        $this->mail->Body = stripslashes($body);
    }

    function sendTo ($to) {
        $this->mail->clearAddresses();
        $this->mail->addAddress($to);

        if (!$this->mail->send()) {
            // echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $this->mail->ErrorInfo;
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}

$batch = new BatchMailer;

$batch->setSubject('sample subject');
$batch->setBody('sample body');

foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $batch->sendTo($email);
}
```

Comment: How does your change addresses "the fastest" problem? You still send messages one after another and the slowest part here is a synchronous network IO.

Comment: @zerkms The single initialization of the PHPMailer class cuts down dozens of function calls and memory allocations. That's an easily measurable difference in execution speed. I don't know enough about his implementation to suggest asynchronous operations, and he didn't ask for alternative libraries.

Comment: that's right. But if you compare execution of your and original code you won't notice the difference. Just because new object creation compared with hundreds of milliseconds of SMTP IO are simply incomparable. I agree that it makes sense to create an object just once, my point is that it won't change anything anyway. Like you know, when someone tells they want to compete with F1 bolid on a skateboard the best advice would be to ask them to use another F1, not simply to put another wheel (or paint the skateboard with another flashy color).

Comment: You're right. In this case, I'm talking about code execution performance, without taking the network into account. Actually I'm not sure asynchronicity could even be applied here, since he's using an SMTP account to send mail on a remote server. I've added the SMTPKeepAlive flag mentioned in @Synchro's response, since that will greatly reduce network overhead.

Comment: Also, I recommend you re-read the title of this question: "fastest way to send mails using phpmailer smtp?" To continue your strange analogy, skateboards are all we have.

Comment: let's continue analogies: when someone wants to lift 10 tons of sand I propose them to use some lifting vehicle instead of just taking a shovel and stretching their hands. The latter will work indeed. But the speed question does not make much sense then - it does not matter if it will take 1 year or 1 year 10 days, it's all the same slow. PS: OP did not say they cannot use additional (see better) software, so why not tell them how to do that "properly" instead of answering being constrained unreasonably :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much of one for analogies, and that excavation one goes beyond me. However, I interpreted the title to mean he can only use PHPMailer, and I have trouble interpreting it otherwise. Hence, I provided the fastest PHPMailer implementation I could muster as requested, shovel and all.

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear. This is my last attempt: when a process takes several minutes to perform, it does not matter if you save 100ms.

Comment: Your point was quite clear since your first comment. Perhaps I have not been quite so clear. I know of the network delays involved, but this question asked how to make his PHPMailer code implementation faster, not devise a completely new system out of C++ or local mailservers.

Answer (score -1):

Drop the function into c++ via cgi. A c++ mailer would be far more robust than hitting the entire http framework first.   http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/86562/
But PhP already uses hash table for it's associative array, so you won't pick up anymore speed with a hash table. So you really are sort of maxed out in your web framework.
Drop it to a system level function and c is your fastest/leanest choice.
Unless you are really talented with assembly language.

Comment: This is really pretty unhelpful.

Comment: It is without question the 'fastest method'. Your situation may not merit it, but if you want max speed, this is the only route.

Comment: @Brad S: "this is the only route" --- it would be right if the question was about high performance computation. Then indeed switching php -> C(++) would make sense. In this case the bottleneck is a network IO, not CPU, so it makes no sense to optimize what is not slow.

Comment: In my defense, the wait time would be moderately less on a c++ driven stack. You still have a couple of layers on the OSI to account for. C++ is like the Honey Badder, it don't care.    :)